# How can I tell what process is asking me for permission on macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, macos-sierra

When I unlock my MacBook Pro, I periodically see a window saying that I must enter admin credentials for debugging to continue. Even though I don't *think* there's any malware on my device, I'm naturally a little leery of just entering those credentials on demand. Is there any way to tell what process is requesting access so I can make that decision in an educated fashion?

It's weird that it only seems to happen when I wake up my laptop after being asleep for hours.

Comment: Could you take a screen shot? I thought that the debugging prompts included the offending party.

Comment: I'll post a screenshot next time it happens. I don't remember seeing any indication of the process requesting permission, though. Thanks!